# Nested route link to two different components

Tags: reactjs, router, react-router-v4

Nested route config

```
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/:user' component={UserReposPage} />
      <Route path='/:user/:repo' component={RepoInfoPage} />
    </Switch>
```

**RepoInfoPage** is not rendering ('/:user/:repo') as expected, it redirects to the **UserReposPage**. how can I make that work?

Comment: What is expected? What are you getting that is *not* expected. Please add more info to the question.

Comment: @BrianThompson updated

Comment: Is it within a `Switch`?

Comment: Yes, it is within switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Switch`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch) only returns the **first** matching `Route`. Your second route will only match if your first does as well. This is why it will never render.

A simple fix may be to reverse the order of your `Route`'s.

```js
<Switch>
  <Route path='/:user/:repo' component={RepoInfoPage} />
  <Route path='/:user' component={UserReposPage} />
</Switch>
```